# javascript obfuscation and license keys

Tags: javascript

i need to send a set of html files to client which includes a license key that should be validate against the input that the user enters. Please suggest how to protect this keys from accessing by client.
I heard javascript obfuscation is a better way to do this. Is it advisable to use this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this [javascript obfuscator tool](http://javascript-obfuscator.org). Its would be suitable for you.
There are couple of reasons you should obfuscate your javascript code:

> - Prevent anyone from simply copy/pasting your work. This is specially
>     important on 100% client side projects, such as HTML5 games.
> - Protection of work that hasn't been paid yet. You can show your work to the client knowing that they won't have the source code until the invoice has been paid.

Answer (score 2):

Deliberate JavaScript obfuscation is never a good idea — a minimal amount of reverse-engineering can easily reveal how the code operates.

Unfortunately, there is no way to have client-side logic protected by any sort of license key or otherwise — as the source is in plain text, the user can very easily circumvent the protection you have in place to access the protected functionality.

You may want to consider implementing the functionality server-side and have the client make requests to the server with an accompanying key.

Comment: Thanks for your input..but in this case its not possible to communicate with server,all the files will be sent to client which will be install in client machine. So what we can do is only protect the key from accessing by the client -like encrypt using algorithm or obfuscation.